# How to know and verify that a user is what it say it is?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the most basic problem.

I make an application. I am also making the server side of the application. My application send message to the server asking for user's password, username, etc.

The user doesn't have password because signing up is through facebook, by the way.

For now, I set up that users require facebook account to sign up to my applications.

However, facebook oAuth token is temporary.

Say I sign up.

Weeks latter I want to request my bookmark. Now how does the server knows that it is indeed the user that ask for that bookmark?

What should I store on the server?

I suppose I can store the facebook username. However, storing facebook oAuth is useless because oAuth is temporary anyway.

So, when designing the server API, how does the server know that it's the same user that's asking for private information?

Is there frame work or PhP for this sort of thing?

What should the app send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to facebooks [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) server-side logins automatically get a long-lived access token which is valid for 60 days, if you're going with client side, or, need to refresh the token there is a method to [exchange the short-lived token for a long-lived token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#step1).

There is also a [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) available to develop your applications with.

In regards to how you know a user is who they say they are, this is handled by facebooks oAuth implementation. The user grants permission to link your application to their account, facebook verifies they are who they say they are and passes the relevant information back to your server, this [process is outlined here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)